# PHP is updating instead of inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a page where the user fill a report and that report is inserted to the database
I have below my php page that is supposed to insert new values to table reports, but it is updating instead

```
<?php 
include 'connectionfile.php' ; 
$ref = $_POST['ref']; 
$title =$_POST['titl']; 
$type = $_POST['type']; 
$content = $_POST['content'];
session_start(); 
$sql = "insert into reports (reference, title,id_type, content) values ('".$ref."', '".$title."', '". $type."','".$content."');"; 
$result =mysqli_query($con,$sql ); ?>
```

Is it because `id_type` (primary key of table type) is a foreign key -in table report- of value 1 and 2?

Because if I insert `id_type=1` for example, id_report (primary key of table report) increments by 1, same goes to `id_type=2`

Answer might be clear,my knowledge in web development was forgotten.

Comment: This is impossible,check for triggers on your table or your definition or Updating might be fuzzy

Comment: your code is open to `sql injections`; escape the input or use prepared statements.

Comment: i have read some sql injections pages, truth to be told i can't understand how to prevent it. Can you please provide me with the correct code?

Comment: @Adnan The value of `id_type (foreign key)` in the `reports table` must exist in the `id (primary key)` of the `type table`. In the `reports table`, if you set the `id (primary key)` as `AUTO INCREMENT` then it will increment by 1, which is Ok.

Comment: yes i did that, right now am re-writing everything with new tables and will see what will happen

Comment: @Adnan what is the error/

Comment: injection-safe code would be $sql = "insert into reports (reference, title,id_type, content) values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$ref)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$title)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$content)."');";

Comment: @hanshenrik thank you for this , is this a good code to follow also? $type= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the SQL-Query you provided, no update is possible. You can make an `UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY`, but this is not in this query. Please note, that you do not have to and should not specify any value for an automatically setted parameter (`AUTO_INCREMENT`).

Comment: you don't have a row called `id_type` in `reports` table.

Comment: @Adnan: The index `id_type` is not defined in your `$_POST` array.

Comment: @hanshenrik: Wrong. This, you can only see in a MySQL error message, which is not provided.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7rj7t3 this code doesn't give a shit about what's in $_POST['id_type'], however, it will give what's in $_POST['type'] as the value for `id_type` in the `reports` table.